# Unit Of Work Pattern and Unity and Generic Repository Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am implementing DI, UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern like below: I am need your expert opnions for this implementation and also I am facing error.

---

```
**Business Domain(Class Lib)**
-Contracts
     -IWelcomeService.cs
-Repositories
     -BaseRepository.cs
     -DataRepository.cs
     -IDataRepository.cs
```

---

```
**EF project Lib (I have autogenerated code for Existing Oracle DB)**
-MyEntities.cs (This is additional file I have added for IUnitOfWork implementation
```

---

```
**MVC3 Project (Left default folders for simplicity)**
-Factories
     - UnityDependencyResolver.cs
UnityContainerSetup.cs
```

---

**Code for these custom implementation is as below**

**MyEntities.cs**

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    #region IUnitOfWork Members

    public void Save()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**IWelcomeService.cs**

```
public interface IWelcomeService
{
    string GetMessage();
}
```

BaseRepository.cs

```
public class BaseRepository 
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }        
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Save();
}
```

DataRepository.cs

```
public class DataRepository : BaseRepository, IDataRepository
{
    public DataRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }

    #region IDataRepository Members

    public string ChangeMessage()
    {
        return "Changed by repository";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

IDataRepository.cs

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    string ChangeMessage();
}
```

UnityDependencyResolver.cs

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    #region IDependencyResolver Members

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object instance;

        try
        {
            instance = _container.Resolve(serviceType);

            if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
                return null;

            return instance;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

UnityContainerSetup.cs

```
public static void Setup()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IWelcomeService, WelcomeServices>();
        container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

HomeController.cs
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IWelcomeService _service;

```
    public HomeController(IWelcomeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = _service.GetMessage();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Issue:
When I run the application I get below error:
"No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Question:
When will UnitOfWork initiated? How do I inject IUnitOfWork while setting up unity container?

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is WebAPI, not MVC, but should work the same way... See here, for an example... http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver